# Jquery Scroll One pixel from where ever the user is on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

okay heres the scenario. I have a one page website with may sections using anchor links. Whe the user is on a secondary layout (page) and when they click on to go to a section on the main page again, for some reason the graphics dont load properly until a scroll happens. All I want to do is whenever the main layout is loaded, no matter which anchor it loads to, simply scroll the page up or down by 1 pixel.

```
 $.scrollTo({ top: '+=100px', left: '+=0px' }, 800);
```

I tried the above, but this code simply takes the user 100 pixels from the top. I don't want that to happen, i.e. not from the top but from where ever the user is on screen.

Answer (score 39):

use jquery scrollTop() to set the scroll position to the current scroll position + 1:

```
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+1);
```

Comment: Perfect what I want. +1

Comment: Be careful not to place this in a loop, or you'll get a neverending smooth scrolldown. Unles that's what you're going for.

Comment: @Justin McDonald This isn't working, instead of window you have to use 'html,body'.

Answer (score 9):

I have a similar problem. I want to scroll down 1 pixel and then 1 pixel up, so the user hopefully won't notice anything at all. I did this:

```
window.scrollBy(0, 1); // 0 pixels horizontal and 1 pixel down
window.scrollBy(0, -1); // 0 pixels horizontal and 1 pixel up
```

UPDATE:
But I might end up using JQuery instead. All I want is the scroll event to fire and I can do that with:

```
$(window).scroll();
```

Answer (score 4):

A pure JavaScript solution without the jQuery overhead:

```
window.scrollY += 100;
```

With jQuery (and a fancy animation):

```
var cur = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).animate({scrollTop: cur + 100});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(window).scrollTop() + 1)});
```